# Changing sfdc header and footer without creating new VF pages

Tags: custom

I need to change the header and footer of standard salesforce pages (sfdc pages) with a custom CSS that I have. Now I am not sure if this is a customer portal (it is probably not). I searched and found out it can be done by changing the Self-Service as given in the following link: http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/create_your_custom_page_header_and_footer_sections.htm

However the problem is when I go to Name | Setup | Customize | Self-Service, I do not see the Self-Service Portal - Settings anywhere (as given in the step 1 of the link). Instead there are two options, 1) Public Solutions 2) Web-to-Case.

Basically what I want is to replace the Blue header and footer of the salesforce standard pages with the CSS given to me. The changes will be in actual org.

Any guesses on how to go ahead with this?

Comment: You cannot change headers / footers in the app out of the box, you'd have to create custom vf / sidebar component. Maybe possible in a portal.

Comment: but doesnt the link states that the header and footer can be changed?

Comment: Only in a Portal - a portal is an external interface, it will not apply in your internal salesforce org.

Comment: Communities which comes out June (Safe Harbour) allows for a completely branded experience.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change the look and feel by replacing the standard pages with Visualforce - we have done this for customers in the past (because they wanted a completely branded and custom UI, not just for a minor tweak) and its a huge amount of work, both in terms of the upfront effort and the ongoing maintenance when you introduce new objects. Essentially you are creating your own front end to Salesforce.  You also can't stop people deep linking or bypassing overrides through URL parameters so it isn't a silver bullet.

Sidebar components wouldn't work in every case as they don't get rendered for reports and dashboard pages, so those would revert to the old look and feel.

Self-service portals aren't available in new orgs as that was discontinued a while back, but that was a very basic portal anyway so wouldn't really have helped.  Portals are reasonably customizable, header, footer, colours, but that doesn't apply to non-portal users accessing through the standard UI.